Go to (CTRL + G) the value of a cell
Can CTRL + G help me go to the value of a cell?
i.g. Cell AE1 v-lookups and returns "D38" (the cell I need to go to).
Can I use CTRL + G to get there?
It's for a recorded macro. I want to record a macro that takes me to the value of AE1, no matter if its D38 or another value. So when I play/push the macro button it will take me to that cell
The macro record would be: Start recording -> CTRL + G -> Type the value of cell AE1 -> Go to the value, which is a cell (D38)

Have you tried it?

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Doesn't pressing CTRL+G, typing D38 and pressing Enter work?

Are you looking for some Index(Match(...)) solution?

Ctrl-G doesn't do that, but you can simply make a macro do this. Just not through recording a macro, you'll have to type it in (or add it to an existing recorded macro).
It's just one line in VBA: Range(Range("AE1").Value).Select
